# How to assign string values to numeric values in a SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Essentially I have a test case scenario where I need to assign calculated percentages to a text value.  E.g. < 80 = 'B'  < 70 = 'C'

Here is the relevant portion of my code that pulls the value into a percent based on number of assignments handed in.

```
Select *...
    100 * COUNT(CASE TurnedIn WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
                             / COUNT(TurnedIn) AS Percentage, 
From Table1
When ...
```

I  have tried wrapping this with a case such as

```
Case when (100 * COUNT(CASE TurnedIn WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
                             / COUNT(TurnedIn)) <= 80  Then 'B' As LetterGrade
```

but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you please show the view/table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write as:

```
    Select *, --name all columns you want
           case when Percentage < 80 then 'B'
                when  Percentage < 70 then 'C'
                else 'Add the grade which should be default when above 2 
                      case conditions are not met'
           end as LetterGrade
    from (      
    Select *,
        100 * COUNT(CASE TurnedIn WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
                                 / COUNT(TurnedIn) AS Percentage 
    From Table1
    When ..) T
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this,

```
With CTE as
(

Select (100 * COUNT(CASE TurnedIn WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
                      / COUNT(TurnedIn))        as Percentage

  from myTable          
)           
select Case When Percentage <70 
            Then 'C' 
            When Percentage <80
            Then 'B' 
            Else 'A'
        End
 from CTE
```

Comment: This could very well work but the second answer is the one I was more familiar with and went with.  Sorry, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kevrone, you have ticked wrong answer, try to run that script with Percentage 50, it will result to 'B', but it should return 'C'.

Comment: Upvoted sir I didn't mark it as wrong I just marked the other one as right.